# Can a table have two columns of same foreign keys using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I need to have 2 columns in table B. Say column_1 one and column_2.
Currently Table B has column_1.

Both column_1 and column_2 are primary key in Table A.

Table A is an Entity Class and Table B is an Entity Class as well.

column_1 is mapped as follows

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "column_1", nullable = false)
private A a;
```

The Question here is, is this possible to do?
If yes how should it be done?

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing while trying to do so?

Comment: I have not yet done it. Just want to know if it is possible.
As i dont have enough time to try it out.

Comment: Try it and you will know.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "column_1", nullable = false)
private A a;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "column_2", nullable = false)
private A b;
```

Map the variables a and b to a list in Class A.